# What is the source of this damp / mould patch?

Tags: brick

I have a patch that has appeared on my outside brick work and I can’t figure out why or where it’s come from. It’s not close to any pipework I can see.  Although it near the boiler outlet it’s not under it. The other side ( internal)?shows not damp at all so somewhat at a loss on how to cure/ prevent it getting worse. It’s only appeared in the last day or so. Or even if I should be concerned

Comment: This could  be from condensation from the hot air from the boiler vent.

Comment: A picture might help.  Have you had rain or even some wind blowing in the direction of the outlet to the damp spot?   On my house, certain damp spots will be seen for a day or two depending if the sun hits them to dry.

Comment: A picture and since this is outdoors it would help to know where you are (country, part of country), the climate, the weather, and which way this wall faces.

Comment: Look at the roof and work your way down. Gutters. Windows. Whole thing needs tuck pointing? The spot's a foot and a half off the ground? Then it's obviously wolves. "Picture *might* help"? Nope... *can't* help you w/o a picture.